# Canvasに描かれたボタン要素をデベロッパーツールで取得したい

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Google chrome のデベロッパーツールを使用しています。
サイトのログインボタンの位置情報を取得したいです。
ログインボタンがcanvasタグで描かれている場合、このcanvas上のログインボタン図位置にポインタがあることをどう判断させているのでしょうか？座標情報・要素情報が見つからずです。。
ご教示ください。

Comment: 言ってることが理解できません。簡単なサンプルでいいので、言ってることを表現している html ソースを提示することはできますか？

Comment: 例えば [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) のインスタンスプロパティの中のどれかの nnnnX, nnnnY の座標位置を元に計算しているとかでは？ ただし該当しそうなJavaScript処理をソースコードで探せる状態ならば可能かもしれませんが、全くの第三者がブラウザのデベロッパーツールで調べるというのは難しい可能性が高いですね。何かで MouseEvent をシミュレートして試行錯誤で探すくらいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

できません（少なくとも標準的な方法では）。

Canvas上のある部分が、人の目から見て他と区別可能な要素として描画されていても、それはHTML（DOM）の要素ではありません。よって、HTML（DOM）の要素を観察するツールで扱うことはできません。

> `<canvas>` 要素は単なるビットマップであり、描かれたオブジェクトに関する情報は提供しません
>
> —— [MDN 『`<canvas>`: グラフィックキャンバス要素』](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas)

例えばゲームエンジンのようなライブラリ／フレームワークで作成されている場合は、そちら側で何らかのツールが用意されているかも知れません。

また、JavaScriptで描画されてクリックに反応しているならば、JavaScriptのオブジェクトとして座標がどこかに保存されていることでしょう。開発者ツールのコンソールなどから観察可能かも知れません。それを行うのなら、ある程度は対象のコードを読み解いて理解する必要が有ります。